# What does "the event of economic consequences" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I read a [paper](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/00251749210014725/full/pdf?title=the-operating-cycle-risk-return-and-opportunities) talking about the Operating Cycle. On page 6th, they said:

> Sales of assets, no matter how disguised, are one-time events. In
> contrast, cycling capital through the cycle and generating cash
> contribution margins from operations hopefully is a **repeatable event**
> and **the event of economic consequences** that justifies the existence of
> a firm. It is the well of economic returns

From my understanding, sales of assets above mean that the company sells the timber, or oil, or cash equivalents, and they are one-time events. Then,"cycling capital through the cycle" means dollar leaves cash and go through other asset account, and $1.05 comes back into cash after a number of days. Then "[contribution margins](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/contributionmargin.asp)" means selling price per unit minus variable cost per unit.

I am wondering why they hope it is **a repeatable event**, and what does "**event of economic consequences**" mean in this sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one is running a business to survive, it must have an operating cycle, wherein *capital*, meaning everything that has been invested in the company, produces economic returns repeatably.

The word "cycle" implies "repeatable".  The author is pointing out that one-time sales of asset are by definition not repeatable. For example, if you sell a big factory so that you can subcontract your manufacturing to other companies, you have done something that can't be repeated. Doing that has an *economic consequence* in that the company receives money for the sale, but just once. Once sold, it can't be sold again.

So, both *one-time sales of assets*, **and** *generating cash ... from operations* are "events of economic consequence", but only the cash from operations is repeatable and sustainable.

Why do they hope returns are repeatable? Because they want to stay in business as a company.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your dedicated explanation, I am wondering your last sentence, why "Why do they hope returns are repeatable? Because they want to stay in business as a company." ? Do you mean that they need to create returns(money) to stay in business?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, that's right. A business is a repeating operation of making money.